# How to install wkhtmltopdf on Docker Ruby-2.5.1 Alpine Linux?

Tags: ruby, docker, wkhtmltopdf, alpine-linux

```
RUN apk --update add ttf-ubuntu-font-family wkhtmltopdf
```

I am trying to install wkhtml using this command on docker image `ruby-2.5.1:alpine` but error is:

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  wkhtmltopdf (missing):
    required by: world[wkhtmltopdf]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk --update add ttf-ubuntu-font-family wkhtmltopdf' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

is there any way to install it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Update your base image, seem like it pulling from **v3.7**, as you can see the error

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
```

Where v3.7 does not contain wkhtmltopdf

[v3.7 wkhtmltopdf not exist](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=wkhtmltopdf&branch=v3.7)

or if you do not want  update the image then you can install it from [v3.10 wkhtmltopdf](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=wkhtmltopdf&branch=v3.10)

```
RUN apk add  --no-cache --repository  http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/ wkhtmltopdf=0.12.5-r0
```

Btw this base image will work without modification.

[2.5-alpine3.9](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/bf0e16e7511c97fdf351fdfc2e7e17478a4eaf16/2.5/alpine3.9/Dockerfile)

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried your second solution because I do not want to update the base image, but there is the new error: '''Step 3/15 : RUN apk add  --no-cache --repository  http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/ wkhtmltopdf
 ---> Running in 2c971af8636b
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  wkhtmltopdf (missing):
....

Comment: can you you share your base image url?

Comment: here is my base image url: https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/c9644fe5c95cd71913db348baa41240f05d882b3/2.5/alpine3.7/Dockerfile

Comment: docker hub link please

Answer (score 3):

Installing `wkhtmltopdf` from the alpine repo doesn't work in some cases due to a missing qt patches. Some images (e.g. https://github.com/madnight/docker-alpine-wkhtmltopdf) have the patches applied and it's possible to use the patched binary as:

```
FROM madnight/docker-alpine-wkhtmltopdf as wkhtmltopdf_image

FROM ruby-alpine

COPY --from=wkhtmltopdf_image /bin/wkhtmltopdf /bin/
```

See also: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/841

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the from ? use

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1-alpine

RUN apk --update add ttf-ubuntu-font-family wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: without from it will never reached to run command. see the question OP using `ruby-2.5.1:alpine`

Comment: thank you, I am using FROM  of course but the error is because in alpine v3.7 wkhtmltopdf does not exists, and I need a way to install it somehow